# Variable Assignment Issues

Tags: variables, unityscript

Good Day Everyone, I am working on a script and it works really well, but there is just this one error that i just cannot figure out. What am i overlooking? I will post the error and code below.

Here is the error:

```
UnassignedReferenceException: The variable gameOverScore of Score has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the gameOverScore variable of the Score script in the inspector.
Score.Start () (at Assets/2dspaceshooter/Scripts/Score.js:10)
```

Here is the script:

```
#pragma strict

var gameOverScore:GUIText;
var gameGUI:GameObject;

private var score:int = 0;
private var isGameOver = false;

function Start () {
gameOverScore.guiText.enabled = false;
guiText.text = "Score: " + score.ToString();
}

function addScore () {
    if(!isGameOver){
        score += 10;
        guiText.text = "Score: " + score.ToString();
    }
}

function doGameOver () {
    isGameOver = true;
    gameGUI.SetActive(false);
    guiText.text = null;
    gameOverScore.guiText.enabled = true;
    gameOverScore.guiText.text = "Score: "+score;
}
```

Comment: Is this _JavaScript_ ? What environment are you running it in?

Comment: I have no clue about Unity but [this forum post](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unable-to-assign-guitext-variable.32344/#post-211288) says making `gameOverScore` into a Prefab will help, whatever that is....

Answer (score 0):

Not that I really recognize your script as simple JavaScript, but it may be that you confuse an object `Score` with the lower case version `score`